# Azure - Deployment already in use - How to publish a Worker Role and Web Role to the same hosted service

Tags: azure

My understanding is I can I have many roles per hosted service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432976.aspx, so why am I told:

[image: Deployment already in use]

when I want to publish my Worker Role to the same hosted service as my Web Role??

**Update:** I tried it anyway and it ended up replacing my Web Role.. :( How am I suppose to publish my Web Role and Worker Role to the same hosted service? Preferably from Visual Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hosted service is basically the home for your app, at .cloudapp.net (or you can map a custom name to it). You then publish to this home. If, in the future, you have a code update, you re-publish. And you may update (leaving IP address intact) or delete+replace (not needed or recommended typically).

Now: What you're doing (I believe) is adding a 2nd role to your already-published hosted service. You may do this, and you may also *upgrade* without delete+redeploy. Essentially the entire package gets re-uploaded (not just the new role), and the two roles will then comprise your hosted service.

This will hopefully all make sense after you publish a few times. <strike>Be sure to enable upgrading (I can't recall where the option is - not in front of my dev machine right now).</strike> I believe the latest 1.6 SDK handles in-place upgrades by default. Not being in front of my dev machine, I can't recall how everything looks when upgrading, but it should be doable from Visual Studio. It most certainly is via the Windows Azure portal.

Comment: no i have two separate solutions two different apps - should i have two hosted services one for each? does each hosted service or each role gets its own IP address?

Comment: Ah - thanks for pointing that out. One solution would have all roles under a single cloud project, which would ultimately be uploaded to a single hosted service and given a single IP address. A 2nd solution with a 2nd cloud project would have to be deployed to a 2nd hosted service (or to the same one, wiping out your old code).

Comment: And each *hosted service* gets one single IP address. All role instances are communicated with via that ip address + port. You might have port 80 and port 443 going to a web role, and maybe port 8000 mapped to your worker role. Then those ports are load-balanced across all instances of those roles. *Internally* to your hosted service, each instance of each role has a unique ip address + port. And... if you configure *internal endpoints*, you can then communicate directly between your role instances.